# Check model's ModelState in FileStreamResult action in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a page that a user selects what he wants to download, the submit button posts the form to

```
public FileStreamResult GetFiles(FileSelectionModel model)
{
   //zips files into one zip
   return File();
}
```

However, what if the model wasn't in a valid state? How do I check it? It wouldn't let me return View() or return RedirectToAction() here

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the return type of your action from `FileStreamResult` to the more generic `ActionResult`, then you can return `View()` or `RedirectToAction()`.

HTHs,
Charles